# Usar rotativa en MVC para generar PDF a partir de una vista con filtros

Tags: asp.net, mvc, pdf, rotativa

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto MVC, quiero generar un reporte en PDF y estoy utilizando Rotativa para ello. El problema es que el reporte en si se genera a raíz de algunos filtros, se puede filtrar por productor o por cultivo y dependiendo del filtro los datos que mostrará en el reporte. Pero al generar el PDF solo puedo hacerlo mostrando todos los datos de la base, sin respetar los filtros anteriormente mencionados.

Métodos en el repositorio:

```
public List<CultivoProductor> PorProductor(String nombreProd) {
            try
            {
                if (nombreProd != null && !nombreProd.Equals(' '))
                {
                    using (contexto = new DFdbContext())
                    {
                        return contexto.CultivoProductor.Where(p => p.Productor.Nombre.Contains(nombreProd)).
                            Include("Productor").
                            Include("Productor.Usuario").
                            Include("Productor.Zona.Departamento").
                            Include("Zona.Departamento").
                            Include("Cultivo").
                            ToList();
                         
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
 public List<CultivoProductor> PorCultivo(String nomCultivo)
 {
      try
      {
         if (nomCultivo != null && !nomCultivo.Equals(' '))
         {
             using (contexto = new DFdbContext())
             {
               return contexto.CultivoProductor.Where(p => p.Cultivo.Nombre.Contains(nomCultivo)).
                            Include("Productor").
                            Include("Productor.Usuario").
                            Include("Productor.Zona.Departamento").
                            Include("Zona.Departamento").
                            Include("Cultivo").
                            ToList(); 
              }
         }
         return null;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
   return null;
}
```

Métodos en el controller:

```
public ActionResult BusquedaCultivosProductor()
        {
            if (Session["documento"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return Redirect("~/Usuario/Login");
        }
        public ActionResult FiltrarPorProductor(string nomProd)
        {
            if (Session["documento"] != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<CultivoProductor> aux = repoCultProd.PorProductor(nomProd);
                if (aux.Count() != 0)
                {
                    return View("ResultadoFiltros", aux);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.mensaje = "No se encontraron resultados.";
                    return View("ResultadoFiltros");
                }
            }
            return Redirect("~/Usuario/Login");
        }

        public ActionResult FiltrarPorCultivo(string nomCultivo)
        {
            if (Session["documento"] != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<CultivoProductor> aux = repoCultProd.PorCultivo(nomCultivo);
                if (aux.Count() != 0)
                {
                    return View("ResultadoFiltros", aux);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.mensaje = "No se encontraron resultados.";
                    return View("ResultadoFiltros");
                }
            }
            return Redirect("~/Usuario/Login");
        }

        [OverrideAuthorization]
        public ActionResult ImprimirReporte()
        {
            return new ViewAsPdf("ResultadoFiltros", repoCultProd.BuscarTodos())
            {
                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                FileName = "Reporte Cultivos Por Productor.pdf"
            };
        }
```

En el método de ImprimirReporte() llamó al método BuscarTodos del repositorio simplemente para que me traiga algo, pero ahí tendrían que ir los métodos de los filtros según corresponda, y eso es lo que no sé como lo haría. Gracias.